# “Method definition not in @implementation context"

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have this code what did I do wrong in it cause debugger in xCode is saying @implementation context heres my code below Thanks if you can help me fix right way or suggest what I should do. There error is there on the line TransitionOne

```
-(IBAction)Transition1:(id)sender
{
   TransitionOne *view2 = [[transitionOne alloc] initWithNicName:@"TransitonOne" bundle:nil];
   view2.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical; // code
   [self presentModalViewController:view2 animate:YES];
}
```

Comment: Well, is that definition inside `@implementation <YourClassName> … @end`?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a typo: try initWithNibName instead of initWithNicName. Because you had the method name wrong, the compiler thinks you are referring to a new method that had not been defined.

Comment: Glad it helped. Enough to tick it as the accepted answer? Just over to the left... Only the question asker can mark an answer as accepted. :)

Comment: Interesting that's not the error you would be getting for that particular typo. "Method definition not in @implementation context" is a totally different issue from misspelling a selector.

Comment: i got an error about nicname thing tho in code so fix that and that helped